# How to: Looping through rows; if(Value1 = Value2){getRow}; else if(Never found row) {delete Value2}

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using loops to go through a list of names on one Spreadsheet and comparing them to a list of names on another Spreadsheet.  If the name exists on Spreadsheet1 but not on Spreadsheet2, it should add that name to Spreadsheet2, but if the name on Spreadsheet2 doesn't appear on Spreadsheet1, it should delete that name on Spreadsheet2. The idea is to make them match eachother.  In order to know what changes and what doesn't in order to add values to the other cells right next to the names. It does this by finding the row these differences are on and then just adding or deleting a cell to the unchanging column with the found row.

However, finding out how to do this accurately has been a bother because I want the function to do it by itself using an onChange() function that activates everytime the list is changed.  The list is coming from a query full of names, it's alphabetical.  There are instances where names are added and deleted from Spreadsheet1 seconds apart from each other which causes the function to get confused on whether it should delete or add information.

At first i just made it compare length of the two sheets for which is longer.  But if names are added and deleted, comparing lengths is a bad idea because they can be equal or it will add when it should have deleted and so forth. Everything gets out of whack is what I'm saying.

So I decided a more accurate, if not longer, method is to find the row that doesn't match on both sheets "falseRow", which is what it already did, and then get the value from Spreadsheet1, let's call it ss1 and ss2 from now on.  It then looks for that same value in ss2.  If it finds the value, it gets the row in ss2 that it falls on "trueRow".

Now, I did kinda manage to make it do this but I don't know how to make it loop over and over and after the loop it determines if it doesn't exist at all.  like if the Value in ss1 can't be found in ss2, then it should add it, or if the value in ss2 can't be found in ss1 then it should delete it.

```
function checkAndPlace() {
  var sos = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet1");
  var sas = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sos);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange('F2').setValue('RUNNING')
  var Avals = s1.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast1 = Avals.filter(String).length;
  var s1LastRow = s1.getLastRow()+1;                           
  var Sheet1DataRange = s1.getRange(1,1,s1LastRow,1);
  var Sheet1BDataRange = s1.getRange(1,2,s1LastRow,1);
  var Sheet1Data = Sheet1DataRange.getValues();
  var Sheet1BData = Sheet1BDataRange.getValues();
  var Sheet1length = Sheet1Data.length;
  var sos2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet2");
  var sas2 = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sos2);
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s2 = ss2.getActiveSheet();
  var Avals2 = s2.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast2 = Avals2.filter(String).length;
  var s2LastRow = s2.getLastRow()+1;
  var Sheet2DataRange = s2.getRange(1,1,s2LastRow,1);
  var Sheet2BDataRange = s2.getRange(1,2,s2LastRow,1);
  var Sheet2Data = Sheet2DataRange.getValues();
  var Sheet2BData = Sheet2BDataRange.getValues();
  var Sheet2length = Sheet2Data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < Sheet1Data.length; i++) {
    var s1data = Sheet1Data[i][0];
    Logger.log(s1data)
    var s1Bdata = Sheet1BData[i][0];
    Logger.log(s1Bdata)
    var s2data = Sheet2Data[i][0];
    Logger.log(s2data)
    var s2Bdata = Sheet2BData[i][0];
    Logger.log(s2Bdata)
    if (s1data + s1Bdata != s2data + s2Bdata){
      var falseRow = i+1
      var s1falseRowARange = s1.getRange(falseRow,1,1,1);
      var s1falseRowAName = s1falseRowARange.getValues();
      var s1falseRowBRange = s1.getRange(falseRow,2,1,1);
      var s1falseRowBName = s1falseRowBRange.getValues();
      var s2falseRowARange = s2.getRange(falseRow,1,1,1);
      var s2falseRowAName = s2falseRowARange.getValues();
      var s2falseRowBRange = s2.getRange(falseRow,2,1,1);
      var s2falseRowBName = s2falseRowBRange.getValues();
      Logger.log('falseRow is '+falseRow+' and its value on Sheet1 is '+s1falseRowAName+' '+s1falseRowBName+' and its value on Sheet2 is '+s2falseRowAName+' '+s2falseRowBName+'.');
      Logger.log("Line: "+i+". Sheets are NOT equal. Sheet1 = "+s1data+", Sheet2 = "+s2data);
      for (var j = 0; j < Sheet1Data.length; j++) {
        var s1data = Sheet1Data[j][0];
        Logger.log(s1data)
        var s1Bdata = Sheet1BData[j][0];
        Logger.log(s1Bdata)
        var s2data = Sheet2Data[j][0];
        Logger.log(s2data)
        var s2Bdata = Sheet2BData[j][0];
        Logger.log(s2Bdata)
        if(s1falseRowAName + s1falseRowBName == s2data + s2Bdata){
          var s2trueRow = j+1
          Logger.log(s2trueRow);
          if(falseRow > s2trueRow) {
          }
          else if(falseRow < s2trueRow) {
          }

        }
        else(
          Logger.log(s1falseRowAName+' '+s1falseRowBName+' is not on Sheet2.  Adding him/her is recommended.')
        )

        if(s2falseRowAName + s2falseRowBName == s1data + s1Bdata) {
          var s1trueRow = j+1
          Logger.log(s1trueRow)
          if(falseRow > s1trueRow) {
          }
          else if(falseRow < s1trueRow){
          }

        }
        else(
          Logger.log(s2falseRowAName+' '+s2falseRowBName+' is not on Sheet1.  Deleting him/her is recommended.')
        )
 }
      return false;

    }
}


  ss.getRange('F2').setValue('')
  }
```

Right now it's all just logs, it's not designed to do anything yet.  But as you can see the `else()` functions at the end of both `if()` functions that are looking for the falseRowNames in the other sheets.  They will keep saying their logs through each row that it doesn't match up.  For example: s2falseRowNames. The name is on the sheet1, but it will run through all rows saying it isn't until it finds the right row where it is and give the row.  I want it to only say he isn't on the sheet if that if() function is NEVER giving an answer.  I can't just put the `else()` function in the `if()` because then it will never be said if the `if()` function never has anything `=` How do I do this?

Comment: Please replace your long script by a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this just to look data up - then no need to create an entire script, simply use VLOOKUP. It's realy powerful, and you can use it very quickly to find the answer (of course I'm assuming it's not part of a full system you trying to develop).

**Here for tutorial:** https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/05/vlookup-google-sheets-example/

Comment: it's part of a lot of things that needs scripts to work.